# Minimization problem convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I'm trying to minimize the function:
$$f(w)=w^T\mu+k\sqrt{w^T\Sigma w}$$ where $w$ is a vector in $W=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n|x_1+...+x_n=1 , x_i \geq 0 \forall i\}$.

The vector $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the constant $k\in \mathbb{R}$ and the symmetric positive-semidefinite matrix $\Sigma\in \mathbb{R}^{n*n}$ are given.

Does this problem have an unique solution? I am able to see that $W$ is convex but I don't think $f(w)$ is convex.
How can I numerically solve the problem? I know some theory of linear and quadratic programming but I' not able to use them in this case.

Comment: Is $k$ positive?

Comment: yes, sorry, k>0

Comment: Thanks.  And we can't assume that $\Sigma$ is positive definite?

Comment: the problem I'm dealing with, it's about covariance/correlation matrices that are in general only semi-definite. Why do you need positive definiteness?

Comment: If $\Sigma$ were positive definite, then $g(w) = \sqrt{w^T \Sigma w}$ would be a norm, and norms are convex.  In that case we could say that $f(w)$ is convex.  I bet we can make a similar argument when $\Sigma$ is only positive semidefinite, but it's not clear to me yet.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  How large is $w$?

Comment: @littleO even if $\Sigma$ is just positive semi-definite (i.e., $\Sigma\succeq 0$), $f$ is convex. It would not be strictly convex, though.

Comment: Oh I see, that will proof the existence of the solutions. good. I'm using R for a little $w$ around 100 elements. Do you have any suggestion on which numerical method to use?

Comment: @John Have you tried the simplest algorithm: projected gradient descent? Keep in mind that if $\Sigma$ is not positive definite you might not have a unique solution.

Comment: Since $w$ is small, I bet you could solve this easily using CVX in Matlab.

Comment: I'll immediately try the two methods you suggested me. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put your problem in a form that CVX can accept, we can factor $\Sigma$ as $\Sigma = L^T L$.  Then 
\begin{align}
\sqrt{w^T \Sigma w} &= \sqrt{w^T L^T L w} \\
&= \sqrt{y^T y} \\
&= \|y\|_2
\end{align}
where $y = Lw$.
The optimization problem can be reformulated as
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}_{w,y} &\quad w^T \mu + k \|y\|_2 \\
\text{subject to} & \quad y = L w\\
& \quad w \in \Delta
\end{align}
where $\Delta$ is the probability simplex.

Here's some Matlab code that solves this problem using CVX:

```
% randomly generate a problem
k = 1;
N = 100;
mu = randn(N,1);

m = 50;
A = randn(m,N);
Sigma = A'*A;

% solve the problem
L = sqrtm(Sigma);
L = real(L);
check = Sigma - L'*L;
max(abs(check(:)))

cvx_begin

    variables w(N) y(N)
    minimize( w'*mu + k*norm(y))
    subject to          
        y == L*w;
        w == simplex(N)

cvx_end
```